# Failed low-quality post audit, why?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Here is the failed audit.  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5053569).

I understand that this answer was deleted, and I agree that the answer was not high-quality. But I did not see a particular reason to delete the answer, it was not a "link-only" answer. It explained some relevant information behind the link. So I figured it "looked ok".

So what in particular about this answer should I have noticed to "recommend deletion"?

Comment: That was just spam; it is a post promoting a template site.

Comment: Ok I can see that. I feel like the question was asking for sites like that though. The question itself kinda had to be answered that way. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: The question is off-topic *because it asks for external resources*; this is why asking for resources or links *is* off-topic in the first place. In the question has already been closed and deleted.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately I wasn't asked to review the question :P I think I woulda caught the question.

Comment: You mean you don't look at the context when reviewing posts? Perhaps it is time you started?

Comment: I absolutely DO look at the context. The audit was on the answer not the question.

Comment: Yes, but the question is shown as context right below it.

Comment: Yes, yes it is. I looked at it. I wasn't really seeking my review privilages to be reinstated, I understand I failed the audit. I was mearly trying to learn and improve. I just think an audit asking review of an answer should not rely on the off-topicness of the question. I will pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this was the post in question:

[image: Audit post]

It was flagged as spam, and when I looked at it I saw a post advertising a theme website by a new user with a suspicious profile. I deleted the post as a result, which validated the spam flag and caused this to be used as an audit case by the system. Posts with helpful spam, "not an answer", or "very low quality" flags get fed in as audits for the review queues.

The real problem was indeed the question, which I closed at the same time and which has since been removed by the asker. Now that I look at it, I see a bunch of other people have linked to Theme Forest, so it's possible this wasn't really spam. We've just seen so much spam from people promoting themes and theme sights that we might be a little more likely to assume that of posts like this.

I've cleared the spam flag on this, which should remove it as an audit case, but it's still a problematic answer.